# useParams not working with useState (React hooks)

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to make a component with a dynamic variable that changes depending on the specific route. I used useParams to extract two variables such as gameName and taskNumber. I also set up the state to make prompt change with these two params. However, I got no luck making it to work. I also tried useEffect. I noticed the state remained as the same as initial value.
Because each game has different tasks in which they have different prompts, I want to use conditional statements to pass in those prompts.

Currently, the path is `/timesup/:gameName/:taskNumber`

```
  const FailScreen = () => {
  const { gameName, taskNumber } = useParams();
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState("");
  if (gameName === "zoomchat") {
    if (taskNumber === 1) {
      setPrompt("[mute callers]");
    } else {
      setPrompt("answers");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <PromptBox
        title="Time's Up!"
        msg={`Oh no! You didn’t find all the ${prompt}`}
      />
    
      <Link to="/">
        <Button/>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Ideally, I don't want to hard code the prompt. It exists in another sibling component  for each game. I'm not sure how I can extract that information to here. I tried useContext but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your component `FailScreen` looks perfectly okay to me. All you need to put this component inside a `Router` component with the `/timesup/:gameName/:taskNumber` path.

So, it should look like this:

```
<Route path="/:id/about">
 <FailScreen />
</Route>
```

Comment: I did that, I didn't have trouble getting the right route. The issue is to make the state change to the prompt I passed in. So far, it showed nothing.